# Why does converting an instant to epoch milli and using these epoch millis for a new instant not lead to comparable Instants?

Tags: java, datetime, java-11

I was trying to save and restore timestamps in a database and stumbled upon this: Why does the second line not return 0?

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
System.out.println(now.compareTo(Instant.ofEpochMilli(now.toEpochMilli())));
```

I was expecting to get an instant that would represent the same moment in UTC, but when comparing the two instants as strings, it can be seen that some digits are cut off. What would be the proper way to store an instant in a database?

Example output from the above code:

> 897000

Output varies between runs but seems to be positive always, meaning that `now` is greater than `Instant.ofEpochMilli(now.toEpochMilli())`.

Comment: Have a look at what `Comparable.compareTo` does [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))

Comment: Depends on your precision requirements and on your database. Many database engines have got a `timestamp with time zone` with at least 6 decimals (microseconds) precision. On few (if any) platforms is the precision of `Instant.now()` finer than this, so it may satisfy your requirements. `Instant` itself has nanosecond precision (9 decimals), so if you require this and your database does not honour it, you will need to find another way. Storing the ISO 8601 string from `Instant.toString()` would be an option. You can recreate the `Instant` with full precision through `Instant.parse()`.

Comment: Just in case you missed it (since noone else has mentioned it) you're printing the result of a *subtraction*

Comment: I just noticed that I expected an Instant, which wasn't what I meant - I expected to get 0 as I thought I'd have to instants representing the same timestamp in UTC.

Comment: You're getting an `int`

Comment: @OleV.V. Windows (tested on Windows 11, probably on other versions too) has a 100ns resolution clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Instant` may represent an instant in time with greater than millisecond precision.

The [`Instant.toEpochMilli()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli()) has this note:

> If this instant has greater than millisecond precision, then the conversion will drop any excess precision information as though the amount in nanoseconds was subject to integer division by one million.

The result of `Instant.ofEpochMilli(now.toEpochMilli())` however can never have greater than millisecond precision.